# Configuration that has bind listening on 2 different ip addresses and resolving queries using response-policy

Tags: linux, dns, bind, bind9

I have a requirement where I need to have a bind server listening on two different private ip addresses. Depending on the server address queried, a particular host entry gets returned.

Server has addresses 10.0.0.1 and 172.16.0.1

For example if I query site.example.com on 10.0.0.1 I get 10.0.0.2 as the response and if I query 172.16.0.1 the address is overridden using a response-policy and I get 172.16.0.2 as the response.

I need some help getting this configuration to work. Ideally there should be no match on the source address, so any host on either network can query either bind address.

The response policy is working fine. It returns my overridden hostname correctly.

I thought that I could accomplish this using views, but from my understanding, the views are read in order and once a match is made it uses that, so if I use  `match-clients { any; };` it will match the first view, even though it has `allow-query-on` set to the corresponding address.

my conf

```
view dns_override {
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-query-cache { any; };
        allow-query-on { 172.16.0.1; };
        allow-query-cache-on { 172.16.0.1; };
        match-recursive-only no;
        match-clients { any; };
        allow-recursion { any; };
        recursion yes;
        forwarders { 10.10.10.10; };
        include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
        include "/etc/bind/zones.response-policy";
        response-policy {
                zone "response-policy";
        };
};

view dns_normal {
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-query-cache { any; };
        allow-query-on { 10.0.0.1; };
        allow-query-cache-on { 10.0.0.1; };
        match-recursive-only no;
        allow-recursion { any; };
        recursion yes;
        match-clients { any; };
        forwarders { 10.10.10.10; };
        include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
};

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
```

How can I configure this so that either view can be accessed by any host?
Is it possible with views?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks